# My input only works sometimes in java but the code is all the same?

Tags: java

My input will not work. It works when you input 1 and 2 but not 3. When you put 1 into the question you get playing and same with 2 but 3 just doesn't work but all of the code is identical except for variable names. I have changed parenthesis locations, variable names, and even framework of the code but nothing worked.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();
        Random rand = new Random();
        String START = console.readLine("Would You Like To Start? (Yes Or No) \n");
        if (START.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            console.printf("Good Bye \n");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (START.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            String Level = console.readLine("What Level? 1,2, or 3 \n");
            if (Level.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                int Repeat = 1;
                while (Repeat == 1) {
                    int numbers = 3;
                    int Add = rand.nextInt(10);
                    int Multi = rand.nextInt(3);
                    int Answer1 = rand.nextInt(10);

                    while (numbers == 1) {
                        numbers = 0;
                        Add = rand.nextInt(10);
                        Multi = rand.nextInt(3);
                        Answer1 = rand.nextInt(10);
                        numbers = 1;
                    }

                    if (Multi > 0) {
                        numbers = 1;
                        int Answer3;
                        int N;
                        int Answer2;
                        // multiply N, Add Random, = Answer //
                        if (Multi == 0) {
                            numbers = 1;
                        }
                        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                        N = (Answer1 - Add) / Multi;
                        if (N % 1 == 0) {
                            if (N > 0) {
                                console.printf("%sn + %s = %s \n", Multi, Add, Answer1);
                                console.printf("n = ");
                                int number = input.nextInt();
                                Repeat = 0;

                                if (number == N) {
                                    console.printf("CORRECT! \n");
                                    numbers = 1;
                                    Repeat = 1;

                                } else {
                                    console.printf("INCORRECT \n");
                                    console.printf("The Correct Answer Was   " + N + "\n");
                                    Repeat = 1;
                                    numbers = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //1n + 2 = 2   example //
                        //1n + 2 = 1 //
                        //1n + 2 = 1//

                    } else if (Level.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        int Repeat2 = 1;
                        while (Repeat2 == 1) {
                            int numbers2 = 3;
                            int Multi2 = rand.nextInt(3);
                            int Answer2 = rand.nextInt(10);
                            while (numbers2 == 1) {
                                numbers2 = 0;
                                Multi2 = rand.nextInt(3);
                                Answer2 = rand.nextInt(10);
                                numbers2 = 1;
                            }
                            if (Multi2 > 0) {
                                numbers2 = 1;
                                int N2;
                                // multiply N, = Answer //
                                if (Multi2 == 0) {
                                    numbers2 = 1;
                                }
                                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                                N2 = (Answer2 / Multi2);
                                if (N2 % 1 == 0) {
                                    if (N2 > 0) {

                                        console.printf("%sn = %s \n", Multi2, Answer2);
                                        console.printf("n = ");
                                        int number2 = input.nextInt();
                                        Repeat2 = 0;
                                        if (number2 == N2) {
                                            console.printf("CORRECT! \n");
                                            numbers2 = 1;
                                            Repeat2 = 1;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        console.printf("INCORRECT \n");
                                        console.printf("The Correct Answer Was   " + N2 + "\n");
                                        Repeat2 = 1;
                                        numbers2 = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (Level.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                                // } else if (Level.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) { //
                                int Repeat3 = 1;
                                while (Repeat3 == 1) {
                                    int numbers3 = 3;
                                    int Add3 = rand.nextInt(10);
                                    int Divide3 = rand.nextInt(3);
                                    int Answer3 = rand.nextInt(10);

                                    while (numbers3 == 1) {
                                        numbers3 = 0;
                                        Add3 = rand.nextInt(10);
                                        Divide3 = rand.nextInt(3);
                                        Answer3 = rand.nextInt(10);
                                        numbers3 = 1;
                                    }
                                    // 4 + N / 3 = 5 //
                                    if (Divide3 == 0) {
                                        numbers3 = 1;
                                        int N3;

                                        // multiply N, Add Random, = Answer //
                                        if (Divide3 == 0) {
                                            numbers3 = 1;
                                        }
                                        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                                        N3 = (Answer3 - Add3) / Divide3;
                                        if (N3 % 1 == 0) {
                                            if (N3 > 0) {
                                                console.printf("%s + N ÷ %s \n", Add3, Divide3, Answer3);
                                                console.printf("n = ");
                                                int number3 = input.nextInt();
                                                Repeat3 = 0;

                                                if (number3 == N3) {
                                                    console.printf("CORRECT! \n");
                                                    numbers3 = 1;
                                                    Repeat3 = 1;

                                                } else {
                                                    console.printf("INCORRECT \n");
                                                    console.printf("The Correct Answer Was   " + N3 + "\n");
                                                    Repeat3 = 1;
                                                    numbers3 = 1;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You in advance i have been working for days on this one problem.

Comment: Properly indenting your code (most editors will help) makes such work *much* easier.

Comment: Thanks I will work on that more and maybe it will help find the problem.

Comment: you have thirteen (!) closing curly braces at the end. Tat is never a good sign.

Comment: `Level.equalsIgnoreCase("1")` - change it to `Level.equals("1")` as `1` does not have a case.

Comment: still didn't work. :(

Comment: I'd suggest that you break this code up a bit and re-evaluate your basic logical flow.  Mostly likely your code simply isn't doing what you think it is, but there's no easy way to tell because it's all in one giant block.

Comment: This is an indentation problem. The if(Level.equals("2")) is at a different level than the other levels. I'm surprised that Level 1 worked. Any good programmer's editor (Atom is good for Linux) or IDE will help you with this.

Comment: I assume an issue with the mixed reading from System.console() and System.in() (via Scanner). The operating system provides only one input channel, you should not use it with multiple classes in parallel.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and reduce the code to a [mcve]? See also [ask].

Comment: @NomadMaker I did not do this beautification. Someone edited it.

Comment: @Quinn I wasn't thinking of the indentation as something beautiful, but rather that your code blocks weren't where they should be. This produces errors. The java compiler is happy to compile any sort of code as long as it is legal. Humans, on the other hand, need to have visual cues to help them see code correctly and with little effort.

Comment: @NomadMaker I've inserted into websites and IDE's but nothing has changed.